# Case function and wildcards

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm looking to add a wildcard for all ZA- systems to reveal them as 'South African' systems. See my code below. Please assist in fleshing this out.

```
SELECT
      v_GS_COMPUTER_SYSTEM.Name0
     ,v_GS_PC_BIOS.SerialNumber0
     ,v_GS_COMPUTER_SYSTEM.Manufacturer0
     ,v_GS_COMPUTER_SYSTEM.Model0
     ,v_GS_OPERATING_SYSTEM.Caption0 AS [OS Type]
     ,v_GS_SYSTEM_CONSOLE_USAGE_MAXGROUP.TopConsoleUser0
     ,v_R_System.User_Name0 AS [Last Logged]
     ,v_GS_PC_BIOS.ReleaseDate0 AS [BIOS Date]
     ,v_GS_PC_BIOS.SMBIOSBIOSVersion0 AS [BIOS Version]
     ,v_GS_LOGICAL_DISK.FreeSpace0
     ,CASE v_GS_OPERATING_SYSTEM.BuildNumber0
           WHEN 9600 THEN 'Windows 8.1'
           ELSE v_GS_OPERATING_SYSTEM.BuildNumber0
      END AS B_NUM_0
     ,CASE v_GS_COMPUTER_SYSTEM.Name0
           WHEN CASE v_GS_COMPUTER_SYSTEM.Name0 LIKE 'ZA-%' THEN 'South Africa'
           ELSE v_GS_COMPUTER_SYSTEM.Name0 
      END AS CC
FROM
    v_GS_PC_BIOS
    INNER JOIN v_GS_COMPUTER_SYSTEM
        ON v_GS_PC_BIOS.ResourceID = v_GS_COMPUTER_SYSTEM.ResourceID
    INNER JOIN v_GS_OPERATING_SYSTEM
        ON v_GS_COMPUTER_SYSTEM.ResourceID = v_GS_OPERATING_SYSTEM.ResourceID
    INNER JOIN v_R_System
        ON v_GS_COMPUTER_SYSTEM.ResourceID = v_R_System.ResourceID
    LEFT OUTER JOIN v_GS_SYSTEM_CONSOLE_USAGE_MAXGROUP
        ON v_GS_COMPUTER_SYSTEM.ResourceID = v_GS_SYSTEM_CONSOLE_USAGE_MAXGROUP.ResourceID
    INNER JOIN v_GS_LOGICAL_DISK 
        ON v_R_System.ResourceID = v_GS_LOGICAL_DISK.ResourceID
WHERE
    (v_R_System.Operating_System_Name_and0 LIKE '%Workstation%')
    AND (v_GS_LOGICAL_DISK.FreeSpace0 IS NOT NULL)
ORDER BY
    [BIOS Date] ;
```

Comment: What's wrong with your current approach? Which result is giving you and which one do you actually want?

Comment: Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 17
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'LIKE'.

Comment: You have 2 Case words in the last column with only 1 END.

Comment: You actually have one extra `CASE` => change `WHEN CASE v_GS_COMPUTER_SYSTEM.Name0 ...` to `WHEN v_GS_COMPUTER_SYSTEM.Name0 LIKE ...`

Comment: Thanks - I get this error now Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 17
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'LIKE'.

Comment: I'm not sure what I"m doing wrong here. I removed the extra case. Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'LIKE'.

Comment: ,CASE v_GS_COMPUTER_SYSTEM.Name0
           WHEN v_GS_COMPUTER_SYSTEM.Name0 LIKE 'ZA-%' THEN 'South Africa'
           ELSE v_GS_COMPUTER_SYSTEM.Name0 
      END AS CC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your CASE statement to this (syntax of CASE):

```
CASE WHEN v_GS_COMPUTER_SYSTEM.Name0 LIKE 'ZA-%' THEN 'South Africa'
     ELSE v_GS_COMPUTER_SYSTEM.Name0 
    END AS CC
```

Comment: Thanks mate, the darn WHEN